# Team A vs Team B - chances of winning

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

Team A has an average season score of 712 points per game over a period of 8 games. Team B has an average season score of 687 points per game over the same period of 8 games.

Team A has outscored Team B 70% of the time this season.

What are the chances of Team A beating Team B judging by these statistics?

Comment: This question is phrased extremely vaguely. Are you asking for the chance that Team A will outscore Team B in the ninth game, for instance?

Comment: Yes. What are the chances Team A outscores Team B in the ninth game?

Answer (score 0):

If Team A has outscored Team B 70% of the time, you can expect a 70% chance that Team A will again outscore Team B in Game 9.

With the given information, this is the best prediction you can make.

===

It is worth noting the scores themselves are irrelevant as you are not given any variance. With large standard deviations (say ~50 points per game), the chance Team A will beat Team B nears 50% (though still higher than 50%).

With small standard deviations (say, ~0.5 points per game), the chance Team A will beat Team B nears 100%.